# how to create a hash table to compare if part of instance variables in a class have ever occurred before?

Tags: java, algorithm, class, hash

Now I have a maze to solve by BFS to find the goal from start point. I need to print some information, so I decide to create a class Node have A, B and C instance variable (Yes I use JAVA). But my question is, during the BFS, I should not expand the node with same A and B. It means, for example, I have expanded the node first(1,2,3), than I should not expand the node second(1,2,5). So I think I should try to build a hash map or hash table. Every time for one node node(x,y,z), I should check is its (x,y) every occurred before. How can I implement it? Will it still be hash time O(1)? All that other way should I design the class? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a hashtable for this. All you will need to do is define the [equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and the [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods. For these as long as you only test of (x,y) and not (z) then any node with the same (x,y) would collide in the hashmap. But does this even matter? Do you have two Nodes with the same (x,y) but different z values? That would be a very strange maze...

EDIT: lastly it sounds like the [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) object would also work and be exactly what you would want to use.

Comment: In fact, there will be node with same (x,y) but different z, they are instance variable not just values. So there will be collide, will it has bad effect? And sorry I don't understand about "the set object"?

Comment: Well if you don't want to look at any two nodes that have the same (x,y) you want there to be a collide. A set works a bit like a hashmap, but there is no value to store, only keys.

Comment: Got it. So if there is collide, is it OK? Or in fact I can create another Class XX just has instance variable x and y, then I just create a hash set to store XX, is that OK? Thank you.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your questions. It all kind of depend son what you want to do. Also please remember to accept answers you think are useful.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of work recursive algorithm is usually the best approach.

Your question suggests an iterative approach requiring the use of global information. The recursive approach would not require this kind of information to be kept and woukd also make your code easier to understand and implement.